# Visio 2013 Background Pattern

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, microsoft-visio-2013

I have multiple big Visio pages, not intended for printing. Therefore, in each of them I'm drawing beyond the default sized page and Visio is extending the drawing space in response.

What I'd like is to have that drawing space different than the default "white". Color background works fine, being extended as I draw, but I'd actually like to have is a "pattern" background, similar to those CSS patterns in websites.

I created a background page, placed a pattern image in one of the edges, and resized it to cover the whole background page. Then I referenced a single foreground page to it, but didn't get what I was expecting. The foreground page is all white, with an area of the pattern I created appearing like a big rectangular unedited shape.

How can I extend the pattern background page to the whole foreground page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these features existed in editions previous to and including Visio 2007 but were removed in Visio 2010.